# Remove last instance of something on a URL for ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am calling an API and the API is a simple one that all I need to do is to add some arguments to the URL and it returns a json file for me.

I have it working but there's one small issue. I need to remove the last instance of `+AND+` in the URL.

Here is the jQuery:

```
var query = "https://api.myurl.com/search="   
var and = "+AND+"
var generalSearch = "x" + and;
var dateRange = "y" + and;
var ageRange = "z" + and;

jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: query + generalSearch + dateRange + ageRange",
        success: function(data)
        {
 }
```

This returns:

`https://api.myurl.com/search=x+AND+y+AND+z+AND+`

I need to have the `+AND+` separators in order for the URL to be valid and the API to work but the way I have it set up includes a `+AND+` at the end of the url which breaks it.

You may be wondering why not just add the `+AND+` to the URL field in the ajax call like this:

`url: query + generalSearch + and + dateRange + and + ageRange"`

The reason why I'm not doing this is because if one of the values are empty or null it will place a `+AND+` in the URL. For example if "generalSearch" is empty then it will return

`https://api.myurl.com/search=+AND+y+AND+z`

Any possible way to remove that last `+AND+` dynamically using any method?

Comment: you are generating the URL  at client side right.? then why adding AND to ageRange

Comment: Why not simple `var ageRange = "z"`?

Comment: this is a very minimal version of my full code, there are tons of variables and tons of inputs so its impossible to tell which variable will come last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `.substring()` combined with `.lastIndexOf()`, this will remove the last instance of `+AND+`

```js
var s = "https://api.myurl.com/search=x+AND+y+AND+z+AND+";

s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("+AND+"));

console.log(s)
```

Comment: Why not simple `var ageRange = "z"`?

Comment: I know assuming is "dangerous" but I would like to think there is a reason that he adds the "and" to it.

Comment: this is a very minimal version of my full code, there are tons of variables and tons of inputs so its impossible to tell which variable will come last

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
query = "https://api.myurl.com/search="
var and = "+AND+"
var generalSearch = "x" + and;
var dateRange = "y" + and;
var ageRange = "z" + and;
var limit=""; //initialise limit string as empty
var limitIsRequired=true; //if u need to specify limit give it as true
if(limitIsRequired){
limit="&limit=1000"; //if limit is needed update limit="&limit=1000" 
}
var urlTopass=query + generalSearch + dateRange + ageRange"; //computing the full url here
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: urlTopass.substr(0,urlTopass.length-5)+limit, //removing the last +AND+
    success: function(data)
    {}
});
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer I like it so far but I am getting an error saying that `a` is not defined

Comment: ok this works but unfortunately for my case I cant use it because I have to add `"&limit=1000"` at the end of my url. I appreachiate your answer though

Comment: u need to add &limit=1000 in every requests?? or for some specific requests?

Comment: Added a logic to handle limit .please check and verify

Comment: I basically just need to add `&limit=1000` to the very end of the url. Carsten gave me an answer that worked so I accepted his answer. I gave you an upvote for your time. Sorry I could not accept your answer.